# How to assign to .component() an isolated scope object, and to access it in it's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a daunting task ahead of me, as i am rather new to AngularJS. Any help, or advise would be appreciated. 
So the goal that i would like to achieve is to have A controller loop through an array of objects, for each objects "compile" or "interpolate" a component, with each of these child component having their isolated scope be the [i]-th object.

I got the component to display an objects value from the model, but not from the isolated scope. And the interpolation display the markup as string, but gets some value in it that it should.

So i am in a bit of trouble figuring it out, how could i accomplish this.

Here is the code for the component:

```
 angular.module('MpWatchModule').component('mPoint', {
    bindToController: false,
    templateUrl: '/NG-MPWatch/Templates/mPoint.html',
    controller: MpDataController,
    bindings: {
        mpdata:'<',
    }
});
```

Here is the template:

```
<div>
   <h2>Test</h2>
    <h1>{{$ctrl.testData}}</h1>
    <h2>{{test}}</h2>
</div>
```

The page markup where i am trying to display:

```
   <li>
     <m-point mpdata="{{mpd.mpData}}"></m-point>
   </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    {{mpd.interTest}}
                </div>
            </li>
```

And the appropriate portion from the controller:

```
   var mpd = this;

    var subScope = {
        testData: 'this is a test',
    }

    mpd.mpData = {
        test: 'object this is an other test',
        };
var templateString = '<m-point id="{{testData}}"></m-point>';
    var interTestLocal = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        interTestLocal += templateString;

    };

    mpd.interTest = interpolate(interTestLocal)(subScope);
```

And here is the output i get:

[image]

Sofar i was just tinkering with it to get it right, 1st i would like to get the object to be the isolated scope of the component, and access it from the template to display. 2nd i would like to loop trough an object array and assign each object to a component, and have its template sent to the DOM.

These objects once on the page, do not need anything from the parent, they should be doing they own thing, and be as efficient as possible when the page load.

Note: $scope.testData is not displaying now due to `<m-point mpdata="{{mpd.mpData}}"></m-point>` which i am aware, it was just an attempt to get the object in there. Othervise it would display the string from the main model.

Thank you in advance.